# How does the "su" command work internally?

Tags: linux, process, su

I am tying to understand how the `su` command work internally.

Say that I did the following:

```
su someUser
```

The following is what I think will happen:

- `su` will ask me for the password of `someUser`.
- `su` will hash the entered password.
- `su` will compare the entered password with the password in the
  `/etc/shadow` file, and if the two passwords are the same, then `su` will
  launch the default shell for `someUser` (which exist in
  `/etc/passwd`), and `su` will set the user IDs and group IDs of the launched shell to the user IDs and group IDs of `someUser`.

Note that `su` has the `setuid` bit set, so `su` will run with root privileges.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but su doesn't directly access `/etc/shadow`, it uses pam for this. ( `/etc/pam.d/su` )

Answer (score 2):

su doesn't do any password stuff in most Linux distros. Instead it delegates authn/authz to [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/) and only handles the user-changing.

Comment: [Yup.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html#PAM)